# ASIHTTPRequest and PHP; how to stream multiple images to a server

Tags: php, iphone, asihttprequest

When I POST some images to my server using:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
[request setData:image withFileName:@"file(0)" andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:fileString];
[request setData:image withFileName:@"file(1)" andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:fileString];
[request setData:image withFileName:@"file(2)" andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:fileString];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

How do I catch this in a PHP script?

I was doing

```
for($i = 0; $i<$imageCount; $i++){

$target_path = "files/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file($i)']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file($i)']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  echo "Image: ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
 } else{
       echo "error uploading";
  }

 }
```

with imageCount the total number of images being sent POSTed in a different variable to the server, but this throws me upload errors each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<$imageCount; $i++){
$target_path = "files/".basename($_FILES['file('.$i.')']['name']); 

if(copy($_FILES['file('.$i.')']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   echo "Image has been uploaded";
}else{
    echo "error uploading";
    print_r($_FILES) ;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $target_path;
$fileVar = "file($i)";
$target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES[$fileVar]['name']);
```

I believe the error is with that files.